# Condition for concurrence of lines in R3 and higher

Tags: geometry, vectors

I am looking for a vector-based test for concurrency of $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}_3$ or higher.

The problem is easy in $\mathbb{R}_2$, but in $\mathbb{R}_3$ and higher a set of lines doesn't necessarily intersect. I can think of a cumbersome way, solving many systems of equations, but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution out there, perhaps involving some determinant equaling zero?

I cannot find a result like this in the literature and haven't come up with anything myself.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you for thinking about it!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{p}_1+t\mathbf{v}_1$ and
$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{p}_2+t\mathbf{v}_2$ be the parametric equations of two lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The lines concur if
$$
\mathbf{v}_1\times\mathbf{v}_2\ne0\quad\text{and}\quad
(\mathbf{v}_1\times\mathbf{v}_2)\cdot(\mathbf{p}_1-\mathbf{p}_2)=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response.  That is the condition for concurrence of two lines in R3.  Perhaps I should have been more clear.  Suppose I have a collection of n lines in Rp (p \neq 3 necessarily), and I am looking for any concurrencies of two or more lines in that collection.  I can take pairs of lines for example, nC2 equations in all, and check them in the way you've proposed, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way to identify all concurrencies. I imagine if such a method exists it will involve looking at the rank of some matrix, or some determinant equalling zero.  Any ideas?